# How to encrypt Ubuntu 14.04 and all data inside Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox, encryption, virtualization

I am testing Ubuntu.
I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 using an ISO file inside Oracle VirtualBox.
My computer is 32 bits, with 4 GB of RAM, and operates with Windows XP-SP3 as the Host system.
Ubuntu 14.04 is the Guest system.
I want to encrypt the whole Virtual Hard Drive where Ubuntu is located (inside a virtual machine).

I was trying to download from a website TrueCrypt for Linux (Using Firefox in Ubuntu I can reach that website where TrueCrypt can be downloaded inside Ubuntu).
But I read somewhere that Ubuntu 14.04 can be fully encrypted from within Ubuntu.
I have several questions.

- In case that Ubuntu (and all data) can be fully encrypted from within Ubuntu, is this encryption really strong?
- In case Ubuntu can be encrypted from within Ubuntu, where can encryption be turned on?
- Should encryption be turned on while installation of Ubuntu is taking place, or is it turned on when Ubuntu has been fully installed within the virtual machine?

I hope my question is clear. My idea is to fully encrypt Ubuntu (inside VM) and all data inside Ubuntu. Is this procedure (encryption of the whole system inside the VM) are all possible? Should I use TrueCrypt (this probably is not possible), or should I encrypt with confidence from within Ubuntu 14.04? What are the steps to encrypt from within Ubuntu? Any advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt your complete installation (beside the kernel which needs to be unencrypted for bootup) during installation process of Ubuntu. Just install another virtual machine and check for that option. It's a little hidden at the disc partition section -- at least it was on 13.x installers.

To encrypt it after installation is possible, but a real pain in the ass for non experienced users.

TrueCrypt as you know from Windows is not working (and TrueCrypt 7.2 is not able to encrypt at all anymore)

Comment: Was this sarcasm?

Comment: I understand Frian. It may not be perfect. It may even be wrong. But any way that communication helps.So I am grateful. There is no a royal way to knowledge. A little bit at a time,and all of a sudden your at the top. And then there usually is another peak to climb. Cheers!